# How can I issue a telnet command in emacs telnet mode?

Tags: emacs, telnet

I need to issue the telnet close command and normally, ^] (Ctrl-]) should work.(can't find any emacs specific telnet documentation)

How can I get the `telnet>` prompt when I connect using M-x telnet within emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the library commentary via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `telnet` <kbd>RET</kbd> shows the following:

```
;; Normally, input is sent to the remote telnet/rsh line-by-line, as you
;; type RET or LFD.  C-c C-c sends a C-c to the remote immediately;
;; C-c C-z sends C-z immediately.  C-c C-q followed by any character
;; sends that character immediately.
```

So you can send the escape character with:

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-]</kbd>